"might be" + "being taken care of"
There is something that maybe is "being taken care of", but I'm not sure it is or not, so I want to say that it "might be". I'm confused as to how to put these 2 together. If I say "this might be being taken care of", it sounds very wrong.
If I add "currently", it sounds a bit better to me: "this might be currently being taken care of". But then, it could be just an impression, because I'm putting something to break the flow on the "weird" part.
So my question is, is it wrong or does it just sound wrong but it's actually correct? And if it's wrong, what would be the right way of putting "might be" and "being taken care of" together?

To avoid the slightly awkward phrase, you could say "is perhaps/possibly being taken care of".

It's perfectly valid and correct to say, "It might be being taken care of."
Yes, "... be being ..." sounds repetitive. In this case I think it sounds fine, but there are plenty of sentences where using the same or similar words two in a row sounds strange and may be confusing. "I thought that that was strange." I try to avoid doing this, but it's not wrong and sometimes avoiding it just makes the sentence more complex and confusing.
Note this is totally different from doubling a word for emphasis. "I am never, never going to marry you!"
